# Fingerprint scanner is detected and seems to be functional, but never matches fingerprint

Tags: drivers, thinkpad, fingerprint

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T440s, and everything is working pretty much out-of-the-box on Fedora 25, except for the fingerprint scanner. It is detected automatically, and flashes when necessary, and seems to "work", however it never matches my fingerprint (it always says that it is not a match). Is there anything I could try? I also saw that this scanner (by Validity) is not officially supported by fprint.

Comment: I installed this rpm https://fedora.pkgs.org/rawhide/fedora-x86_64/libfprint-0.7.0-1.fc27.x86_64.rpm.html and it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current release of libfprint(0.6.0) is not working great with the sensors used in recent Lenovo. On my T550, it only ask me to swipe once when enrolling a finger and then fail to recognize it 9/10 times.

If I'm updating to the version in [git HEAD](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/) it asks me to swipe my finger 5 times and then the recognition is working way better.

So you should probably try to compile the [git HEAD](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/) yourself and try again.

I would also suggest you to open a bug on the [Fedora bugtracker](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/).

Comment: Sounds good, but I'm having trouble building libfprint. When I try to run ./configure, it complains about missing dependencies, even though the dependencies are installed on my system under a different name. Additionally, when I try to use sed to change the name in the configure file, it still complains.

Comment: What do you mean by `under a different name`?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out (I needed the `-devel` versions of the packages, not just the standard ones), but I'm still having issues. I successfully built the package (`./autogen.sh; ./configure; make; sudo make install`), but the standard fprintd doesn't "see" the custom libfprint that I built, and when I try to install fprintd from the repos it just reinstalls the prebuilt version of libfprint, ignoring the custom one. How can i make the prebuilt fprintd use my custom-built libfprint?

Comment: The best option IMHO is to rebuild the libprint rpm.

One other option, might be to install the library in `/usr/local/lib(64)` but I'm not sure if this location takes precedence over `/usr/lib(64)`

Comment: How would I rebuild the rpm?